# Regex convert [URL](Text) to HTML link

Tags: javascript, regex

`[http://url.com](Here is a link to explain.)`

What regex would replace this with:

`<a href="http://url.com">Here is a link to explain.</a>`?

```
str.replace(/\[(\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])\]/ig, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>")
```

This makes `[http://url.com]` become a link with `http://url.com` as the text, but I need to have the text be replaced inside `()`.

Comment: You seem to be interested in converting several markdown style strings to HTML based on your other questions.  Why not just use a markdown parser library?

Comment: I don't know what to search for / how to use such a thing

Comment: marked.js is a nice one it appears: https://github.com/chjj/marked.  Here's a quick example usage: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/07ozc5df/

Comment: Note that in that demo the link works.  It's just that jsfiddle blocks the navigation it seems.

Comment: Well that's by far the most useful thing I've discovered tonight. Thank you so much! Saved me a lot of trouble and question-asking.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I can't seem to find any info on all the different options? For example how to do underline and strikethrough.

Comment: Underline is a unique circumstance (see here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/207727/why-there-is-no-markdown-for-underline).  For strikethrough and other syntaxes, [this link](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) seems to be a good resource.

Answer (score 2):

This will match those and extract each part as separate matches:

```
/\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)/
```

```js
var regex = /\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)/,
    matches = regex.exec('[http://url.com](This is the text)');
document.querySelector('pre').innerText += matches[1] + '\n' + matches[2];

// create a link
var linkText = '<a href="' + matches[1] + '">' + matches[2] + '</a>';
document.querySelector('pre').innerText += '\n' + linkText;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```